# How to modify frame to 0 in motionbuilder?

Tags: autodesk, motionbuilder

I imported c3d file in motionbuilder, and found out the motion data actually starts from  175000.
Is there a way to start the animation from frame 0?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

No need to script anything. Motionbuilder lets you input the start frame when importing your c3d file.
File > Motion File Import
[image: mobu import options]

Answer (score 0):

You can try using the DopeSheet or timeline bar, select all objects, and respective keyframes and offset them manually. Note that MotionBuilder's UI doesn't do well with very large selections. If you have one point cloud it might not be too bad, but if you have several and an already crowded scene, this method will be frustrating.

The other option, assuming you can script in Python, would be to iterate all of the optical nodes, and offset all of their keyframes by -175000 frames.

If you need a starting point on scripting in Mobu: http://awforsythe.com/tutorials/pyfbsdk-1